# Any possible way to encrypt SQL Server 2012 database or backup?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security, encryption

We don't have SQL Server 2014 or later versions, so I can't take advantage of the backup encryption enhancement available in those. But I would like to know if there are any ways to use any type of encryption for a SQL Server 2012 databases. It could be encrypting the database, backup, or any other object. Any help is appreciated along with the scripts to do so if available.

Comment: Have you considered using powershell to compress it with a password?  I would highly recommend test restoring regularly as a best practice but especially if you go this route.  That's a free solution, RedGate/LiteSpeed or 3rd party tools also have backup encryption on the fly.

Comment: I haven't considered compressing with password and locking it with password. Have you done this on any database before?

Comment: I have done it yes.  I've noticed a slightly more chance to see a failed restore from backup but that could be due to many things.  Just always test restore important backups

Comment: Yeap testing shall be the golden rule.

Comment: If the purpose of this is to meet any security standard for encryption, a zip file with a password does not qualify. Just an FYI.

Comment: You can simply encrypt your SQL Server database backups using SQLBackupAndFTP - https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/supported-zip-file-encryptions

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to utilize encryption in SQL Server 2012.  Here is an article that goes into further detail:
http://sqlmag.com/database-security/sql-server-encryption-options

Note, transparent data encryption is only available in Enterprise edition. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx